# lxml How Can I Target And Retrieve Multiple Element Values?

Tags: python, lxml, screen-scraping

please consider the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><h5>Title 1</h5><div><span>Apples</span></li>
            <li><h5>Title 2</h5><div><span>Bananas</span></li>
            <li><h5>Title 3</h5><div><span>Grapes</span></li>
            <li><h5>Title 4</h5><div><span>Pears</span></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using lxml, I can easily retrieve the h5's:

```
from lxml import html

example_html = '''<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><h5>Title 1</h5><div><span>Apples</span></li>
            <li><h5>Title 2</h5><div><span>Bananas</span></li>
            <li><h5>Title 3</h5><div><span>Grapes</span></li>
            <li><h5>Title 4</h5><div><span>Pears</span></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>'''

tree = html.fromstring(example_html)

element_list = tree.xpath('//h5')

# List comprehension to get text
result = [i.text for i in element_list]

print(result)
```

From that code, of course the result will be:

```
['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4']
```

But I need to know how to produce a result like this:

```
['Title 1', 'Apples', 'Title 2', 'Bananas', 'Title 3', 'Grapes', 'Title 4', 'Pears']
```

I tried modifying the code like this:

```
collector = []
for i in element_list:
    h5 = i.xpath('//h5')
    collector.append(h5[0].text)
    span = i.xpath('//span')
    collector.append(span[0].text)

print(collector)
```

But got this result (close but not quite):

```
['Title 1', 'Apples', 'Title 1', 'Apples', 'Title 1', 'Apples', 'Title 1', 'Apples']
```

Is this possible somehow? I got as far as the above code and any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Have you tried to print the attributes of `tree` ? Maybe there is a way to get those strings by looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union, which returns result in document order.

```
e=tree.xpath("//li/h5|//li/div/span")
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked with 
[i.text for i in e].  Sincerely impressed with "union".  I had no idea!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with lxml, but I have worked with beautiful soup. In case you are okay with switching try the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example_html = '''<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><h5>Title 1</h5><div><span>Apples</span></li>
            <li><h5>Title 2</h5><div><span>Bananas</span></li>
            <li><h5>Title 3</h5><div><span>Grapes</span></li>
            <li><h5>Title 4</h5><div><span>Pears</span></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(example_html, 'html.parser')
list = []
for elem in soup.findAll('li'):
    list.append(elem.find('h5').text)
    list.append(elem.find('span').text)

print(list)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, maybe you'll like it.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><h5>Title 1</h5><div><span>Apples</span></li>
            <li><h5>Title 2</h5><div><span>Bananas</span></li>
            <li><h5>Title 3</h5><div><span>Grapes</span></li>
            <li><h5>Title 4</h5><div><span>Pears</span></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
lis = doc.selects('li>(h5,span)')
print (lis)
```

Result:

```
[['Title 1', 'Apples'], ['Title 2', 'Bananas'], ['Title 3', 'Grapes'], ['Title 4', 'Pears']]
```